# Ionic 5 passing http data to modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, httprequest

I'm making this post today because I have a problem with my ionic application. 
 So here it is, I get the latest news via an API (NewsAPI). The http request returns an arrey with 20 articles that I display in cards with *ngFor='let article of articles'. 
 When we click on these cards, a modal opens. I would like to pass the data of the article in the opened modal. 
 Do you know how this is possible? Since the http request does not return the data of a single article but of 20.

For example, I can't figure out how I can get the data from the 4th article and pass it into the modal of this one. 
Thanks for your help in advance. Sincerely Jules.

the main page.html with the 20 articles :

```
<ion-card *ngFor='let article of articles; let i = index' (click)="openArticle(i)">
    <img [src]='article.urlToImage'/>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{ article.author }}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-title>{{ article.title }}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{ article.description }}  
    </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
```

The main page.ts :

```
export class HomePage {
  searchText = '';
  newsApiUrl = '';
  articles: any = [];

  page = 1;

  constructor(private route: Router, public http: HttpClient, public alertController: AlertController, public toastController: ToastController, public modalController: ModalController) {
    this.topNews();
  }

  readAPI(URL: string) {
    return this.http.get(URL)
  }

  topNews() {
    this.newsApiUrl = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=fr&page=' + this.page.toString() + '&apiKey=MYAPI'
    this.readAPI(this.newsApiUrl)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.articles = data['articles'];
      console.log(this.articles);
      if(this.articles.length == 0){
        this.page--;
        this.topNews();
        this.noMorePageToast();
      }
    });
  }

  async getArticleDetails(id) {
    let article = null;
    this.newsApiUrl = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=fr&page=' + this.page.toString() + '&apiKey=MYAPI'
    this.readAPI(this.newsApiUrl)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      article =  data['articles'][id]
    });
    return article;
  }

  async openArticle(id) {
    console.log('article n°'+id);
    const articleDetails = this.getArticleDetails(id);
    console.log(articleDetails); // Console : [object Promise]

    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ArticlePagePage,
      componentProps: {   
        article: articleDetails    
      },
      mode: 'ios',
      swipeToClose: true
      // cssClass: 'article-page'
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
}
```

The modal page.ts :

```
export class ArticlePagePage implements OnInit {

  @Input() article;

  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss({
      'dismissed': true
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be to call the openArticle function when touching the article and then inside the function call to another function that returns the article details something like this:

```
    async openArticle() {

        // Call to another function that returns article details
        const articleDetails = getArticledetails(id);

        const modal = await this.modalController.create({
          component: ArticlePagePage,
          componentProps: {
            article: articleDetails 
          },
          mode: 'ios',
          swipeToClose: true
          // cssClass: 'article-page'
        });
        return await modal.present();
      }


     async getArticleDetails(id){
       // Call to the API and returns the article details
      }
```

And then on the modal get the article details:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-page',
  templateUrl: './article-page.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-page.page.scss'],
})
export class ArticlePagePage implements OnInit {

  @Input() article // This is the article you passed before open the modal

  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss({
      'dismissed': true
    });
  }

}
```

Please let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Now I see that you can't retrieve a single article on the API then what you could do is to send a parameter on the onClick declaration like (click)="openArticle(article)" and then inside the function pass the article to the modal

Comment: I made some changes thanks to your indications. But I can't store the information of the articles in the variable let article and I don't understand why. (I edited my question with the new code)

Comment: If when loading the page you store the articles inside an array you don't need to call to the api again to show the modal with the article. Using the i from the loop you can access directly to the position on the array. Because I understand that you can list all the articles and when you click to open the modal you can see on the console the i value, right?

Comment: you're totally right and I just realized how this is just inattention on my part. I'll respond to the post clearly if anyone else needs it. Anyway thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad to help you. Could be possible to you to mark my answer as valid? :) Thank you